subinfinity categories
Hey I have the following question. Let $C,D$ be two infinity categories (i.e simplicial sets with inner horn filling condition). $D$ is a subsimplicial set of $C$ if we just take some simplices from $C$ s.t everything matches (i.e if we have a simplex inside all its subsimplices are also inside).
I now saw the definition that $D$ is called  a infinity subsimplicial set of $C$ if it is a simplicial one and $hD \to hC$ is an inclusion of ordinary categorys. I am not sure how to think about this extra condition. What does this mean intuitively? Moreover, I need an example of two infinity categories $C,D$ s.t $D$ is a subsimplicial set of $C$ but not a sub infinity category (i.e $hD \to hC$ is not an inclusion of categories). Anyone has any ideas? (I thought about taking nerves of some groupoid but then I thought that this cant work, as $h(N(C)) = C$ so this procedure will not allow me to create a bigger category taking $h$).

Intuitively, an $\infty$-category is a collection of objects, $1$-morphisms between those objects, and for $k\geq 2$ invertible $k$-morphisms between $(k-1)$-morphisms, where invertibility is to be interpreted in some weak sense (i.e. up to higher morphisms that are themselves invertible). Moreover, we want to have identities and composition operations for all those different kinds of morphisms and have certain demands on those operations, namely associativity and the like. In more detail, if $\mathcal{D}$ is an $\infty$-category, then $2$-morphisms in $\mathcal{D}$ encode composition of $1$-morphisms, in the sense that two $1$-morphisms $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Y\to Z$ compose to $h\colon X\to Z$ if we can find a(n invertible) $2$-morphism $H$ from some "strict" composition $gf$ to $h$. (I am following here a so-called globular approach to higher morphisms, while quasicategories follow a more simplicial approach. Don't worry too much about where the strict composite $gf$ comes from.) So, every composition is "witnessed" by a $2$-morphism, and every $2$-morphism witnesses some composition. The $k$-morphisms for $k\geq 3$ witness in a similar way associativity of composition of $1$-morphisms.
A sub-$\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$ of an $\infty$-category $\mathcal{D}$ should at least be some choice of objects and $1$-morphisms in $\mathcal{D}$ that are closed under the composition "law" of $\mathcal{D}$. But unlike in $1$-categories, where we truly have a composition law, in $\infty$-categories this has become structure encoded in the higher morphisms. If I have two composable morphisms in a subcategory $\mathcal{C}$, then I would want any composite to also lie in $\mathcal{C}$. If in $\mathcal{C}$ I leave out some $2$-morphisms from $\mathcal{D}$ that map between $1$-morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$, then I do not have access in $\mathcal{C}$ to all possible composites of a pair of composable morphisms, and this means the composition structure of $\mathcal{D}$ would not truly restrict to $\mathcal{C}$. So I need to have in $\mathcal{C}$ all those $2$-morphisms from $\mathcal{D}$ that map between $1$-morphisms that I have chosen to be in $\mathcal{C}$. For a similar reason you need all $k$-morphisms for $k\geq 3$ to be contained in $\mathcal{C}$: these higher morphisms encode associativity of composition, and in order for the composition structure of $\mathcal{D}$ to restrict to $\mathcal{C}$ you need all of them (as long as they map between lower-degree morphisms that were already known to be in $\mathcal{C}$), because otherwise some parts of the associativity "law" in $\mathcal{D}$ are not accessible inside $\mathcal{C}$.
This means that the data of a sub-$\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathcal{D}$ is that of some $\infty$-category, whose objects and $1$-morphisms are chosen from $\mathcal{D}$. The $k$-morphisms for $k\geq 2$ must be all of those in $\mathcal{D}$ that map between lower-degree morphisms that are already known to lie in $\mathcal{C}$, which is what the pullback square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{C} @>>> \mathcal{D}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
N\mathrm{h}\mathcal{C} @>>> N\mathrm{h}\mathcal{C}
\end{CD}
$$
from the formal definition means. Here we already used that we want the $1$-morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$ to actually be closed under some composition in $\mathcal{D}$, which is exactly the condition that $\mathrm{h}\mathcal{C}\to\mathrm{h}\mathcal{D}$ should be a subcategory inclusion.
Finally, and example of an inclusion $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ of simplicial sets between two quasicategories that is not witnessing a sub-$\infty$-category: we take $\mathcal{D}$ to be the pushout
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Delta^{\{1,2\}} @>{\mathrm{inclusion}}>>\Delta^2\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\Delta^0 @>>> \mathcal{D}
\end{CD}
$$
where $\Delta^{\{1,2\}}$ is $\Delta^1$ but with the vertices labelled $1$ and $2$ instead of $0$ and $1$, and the upper horizontal map is the unique inclusion that preserves the names of the vertices. We take $\mathcal{C}$ to be the $1$-skeleton of $\mathcal{D}$. Then $\mathrm{h}\mathcal{C}$ is the category $\bullet\rightrightarrows\bullet$ of two parallel non-equal arrows, but $\mathrm{h}\mathcal{D}$ is just the one-arrow category $\bullet\to\bullet$. The map $\mathrm{h}\mathcal{C}\to\mathrm{h}\mathcal{D}$ is the unique functor that is injective on objects, and hence not a subcategory inclusion.
The idea of the example is just that in $\mathcal{D}$ we had a $2$-simplex witnessing both parallel morphisms as homotopic, while we made sure to not include that in $\mathcal{C}$, so $\mathcal{C}$ no longer thinks that these parallel arrows are the same.

thank you for your answer, what do you mean by $\Delta^{1,2}$ and what are the maps in the pushout diagram. (I never saw this notation)

Sorry! $\Delta^{{1,2}}$ is isomorphic to $\Delta^1$, but the vertices are labelled $1$ and $2$ instead of $0$ and $1$. The morphism $\Delta^{{1,2}}\to\Delta^2$ is the inclusion map that sends each vertex to the vertex of $\Delta^2$ with the same name, so it is the inclusion of the face of $\Delta^2$ opposite to the vertex $0$. (More generally, given a finite totally ordered set $E$ of cardinality $n$, people sometimes write $\Delta^E$ for $\Delta^n$, but with the vertices labelled with the names of the elements of $E$ (in the correct order).

sorry one last question, why are $C,D$ infinity categories?

That is something you can check by hand in this case: the simplicial sets are small enough that there actually are no "non-trivial'' inner horn lifting problems.
